# load always n number of images in a div with window scroll

Tags: jquery

I have a json having 100 numbers of image information. I always want to load 10 images into a `.container` div when window's scroll bar touches the bottom such that it replaces the previous set of images(in this case it should replace previous 10 images) in the DOM.

In the `.container` div's DOM also it must always have 10 images, you can inspect in the browser's console to verify it. How can I do it in jQuery?

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
 var informationArray = [];
 var recordCountIndex = 0;
 var recordCountRow = 5;
 var recordCountOffset = recordCountRow;
 var viwPortDisplay = 5;
 var slno= 0;
 getData(recordCountIndex,recordCountOffset);
 function getData(recordCountIndex,recordCountOffset){//recordCountIndex1,recordCountOffset1
 
  $.ajax({
   url: "data.json",
   dataType: "json",
   //async:false,
   success: function(data) { //console.log(data);
    console.log(recordCountIndex+"----"+recordCountOffset);
    var temp = data.data1.slice(recordCountIndex,recordCountOffset);
    if(temp.length>0){
     $divHtml = "";
     $.each(temp, function(index, value) {//console.log(value);
      informationArray.push(value);
      $divHtml +='<div div-index="'+slno+'" class="pageSection">Image-'+ ++slno+'<img src="'+value['name']+'" alt=""></div>';
     });
     $('.container').html($divHtml);
     //console.log(informationArray);
     recordCountIndex = recordCountIndex+recordCountRow;
     recordCountOffset = recordCountOffset+recordCountRow;
     $(window).bind('scroll', function() {console.log("kkkk");

      var windowTop = Math.max($('body').scrollTop(), $('html').scrollTop());
      
      $('.pageSection').each(function (index) {  
       if (windowTop > ($(this).position().top - 150))
       {
        //console.log(windowTop+"---"+index);
        $('#navigation a.current').removeClass('current');
        $('#navigation a:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('current');
        if(index==recordCountRow-1){
         getData(parseInt($(this).attr('div-index')),recordCountOffset+recordCountRow);
         $(window).unbind('scroll');
        }
         
       }
       
      });
     
     }).scroll(); 
     //console.log(recordCountIndex+"----"+recordCountOffset);
    }else{
     //alert("no more record");
    }
   }
  });
 }
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  // console.log("kkkk");

  var windowTop = Math.max($('body').scrollTop(), $('html').scrollTop());
  
  $('.pageSection').each(function (index) {  
   if (windowTop > ($(this).position().top - 150))
   {
    //console.log(windowTop+"---"+index);
    $('#navigation a.current').removeClass('current');
    $('#navigation a:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('current');
    if(index==recordCountRow-1){
     getData(parseInt($(this).attr('div-index')),recordCountOffset+recordCountRow);
     $(window).unbind('scroll');
    }
     
   }
   
  });
    
 }).scroll();
});

    data={
"data1":[
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=1"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=2"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=3"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=4"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=5"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=6"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=7"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=8"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=9"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=10"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=11"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=12"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=13"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=14"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=15"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=16"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=17"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=18"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=19"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=20"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=21"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=22"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=23"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=24"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=25"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=26"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=27"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=28"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=29"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=30"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=31"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=32"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=33"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=34"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=35"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=36"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=37"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=38"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=39"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=40"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=41"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=42"},
   {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=43"}

  ]

}
```

```css
.container { width: 600px; margin:10px auto;}
.container img { border-radius:5px; margin:20px auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="container">
</div>
```

So far I have done this..can anyone extend it to reach the goal

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery loadScroll Plugin Demo</title>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
.container { width: 600px; margin:150px auto;}
.container img { border-radius:5px; margin:20px auto;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jQuery.loadScroll.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var informationArray = [];
    var recordCountIndex = 0;
    var recordCountRow = 5;
    var recordCountOffset = recordCountRow;
    var viwPortDisplay = 5;
    var slno= 0;
    getData(recordCountIndex,recordCountOffset);
    function getData(recordCountIndex,recordCountOffset){//recordCountIndex1,recordCountOffset1

        $.ajax({
            url: "data.json",
            dataType: "json",
            //async:false,
            success: function(data) { //console.log(data);
                //console.log(recordCountIndex+"----"+recordCountOffset);
                var temp = data.data1.slice(recordCountIndex,recordCountOffset);
                if(temp.length>0){
                    $divHtml = "";
                    $.each(temp, function(index, value) {//console.log(value);
                        informationArray.push(value);
                        $divHtml +='<div div-index="'+slno+'" class="pageSection">Image-'+ ++slno+'<img src="'+value['name']+'" alt=""></div>';
                    });
                    $('.container').html($divHtml);
                    //console.log(informationArray);
                    recordCountIndex = recordCountIndex+recordCountRow;
                    recordCountOffset = recordCountOffset+recordCountRow;
                    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {//console.log("kkkk");

                        var windowTop = Math.max($('body').scrollTop(), $('html').scrollTop());

                        $('.pageSection').each(function (index) {  
                            if (windowTop > ($(this).position().top - 150))
                            {
                                //console.log(windowTop+"---"+index);
                                $('#navigation a.current').removeClass('current');
                                $('#navigation a:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('current');
                                if(index==recordCountRow-1){
                                    getData(parseInt($(this).attr('div-index')),recordCountOffset+recordCountRow);
                                    $(window).unbind('scroll');
                                }

                            }

                        });

                    }).scroll(); 
                    //console.log(recordCountIndex+"----"+recordCountOffset);
                }else{
                    //alert("no more record");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    $(window).scroll(function() {//console.log("kkkk");

        var windowTop = Math.max($('body').scrollTop(), $('html').scrollTop());

        $('.pageSection').each(function (index) {  
            if (windowTop > ($(this).position().top - 150))
            {
                //console.log(windowTop+"---"+index);
                $('#navigation a.current').removeClass('current');
                $('#navigation a:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('current');
                if(index==recordCountRow-1){
                    getData(parseInt($(this).attr('div-index')),recordCountOffset+recordCountRow);
                    $(window).unbind('scroll');
                }

            }

        });

    }).scroll();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>


data={
"data1":[
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=1"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=2"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=3"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=4"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=5"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=6"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=7"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=8"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=9"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=10"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=11"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=12"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=13"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=14"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=15"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=16"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=17"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=18"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=19"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=20"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=21"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=22"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=23"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=24"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=25"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=26"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=27"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=28"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=29"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=30"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=31"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=32"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=33"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=34"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=35"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=36"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=37"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=38"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=39"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=40"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=41"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=42"},
            {"name" : "https://unsplash.it/600/350?image=43"}

        ]

}
```

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried till now.

Comment: I have shared my code. This binds the data with scroll down but i want it should always display 10 image on view div and as well as in DOM also. And ajax call will happen only scroll down not in scroll up. In scroll up it will take data from the informationArray.

Comment: Can you please tell what is the problem in the above code, I can see that the images are loading perfectly on scroll?

Comment: inspect and check it appends the div to container div with respect to scroll

Comment: but i want its should show 10 divs in DOM

Comment: In front end it will display images one after another...but in DOM number of div should always 10

Comment: Do you want to fit 10 images in the view or at any time in the view you want to have 10 `image` divs in `.container` div in DOM?

Comment: suppose on body load it will take 10 images from json and will bind it to container div. On scrolling after 10th image it will take another 10 image 11-20. And so on. when you inspect it will show you 1-20 div's in container.Here I want not all div 1-20 but 11-20 and next 21-30 and so on

Comment: Here is what I want to achieve :

Comment: I understood your question now. Thanks for explaining it.

Comment: It should be purely like a virtual scroll using body scroll.

Comment: you can just replace existing one by setting html of parent container to have new images

Comment: @Raimonds That does not work in the current code, it directly goes to the last 10 set of images. The result it not smooth.

Comment: So you basically want to keep 10 DOM nodes at all times, and get new set of images? If so you will need to scroll back to top each time you reach last image, what if you do it by one image not 10
Like if you reach last image it just uploads next and removes first, this should result in smooth transition, kinda. Also why do you want to keep 10 nodes at all times, they are already there, where is the point of getting rid of them?

Comment: @Jagadish, I have edited the question based on our conversation above so that others can get a clear idea. Please make changes to it if you feel it is different from what you had asked initially. I have also removed the AJAX part and made it work, so that community members can try the code here itself on Stack Overflow

Comment: @Raimonds I tried to create a virtual scroll container on body scroll where data should load on scroll and previous data should be removed at the same time. As I scroll up, those previous data should be updated in DOm and new data should be removed.

Comment: Updated the code. Please do check and let me know if anything possible!!!